# Как правильно объявить глобальную переменную в классе?

Tags: php

Решил познакомится с классами, и встретил такую ошибку:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on null in C:\servers\WWW\engine\engine.php:14 Stack trace: #0 C:\servers\WWW\index.php(5): le->query('SELECT * FROM `...', Array) #1 {main} thrown in C:\servers\WWW\engine\engine.php on line 14
```

Мой код:

```
class le {

function __construct() {
$set  = json_decode(file_get_contents('engine/settings.json'), true);
$lang = json_decode(file_get_contents('engine/languages/'.$set['ui']['language'].'.json'), true);
$tpl  = unserialize(file_get_contents('engine/templates/'.$set['ui']['template'].'.serialize'));
$db   = new PDO('mysql:host='.$set['db']['host'].';dbname='.$set['db']['name'].';charset=utf8',$set['db']['user'],$set['db']['pass']);
}

public function query($sql, $params)
{
    global $db;
    $query = $db->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute($params);
    return $query;
}

....
```

Судя по ошибке я понял что функция 'query' не может найти переменную 'db'.

Как сделать так что бы данная функция имела доступ к 'db'?

При чем при каждом вызове функции 'db' не должна заново инициализироваться.

И вообще, как стоит правильно делать глобальные переменные в классах?

Comment: сделать полем класса надо

Answer (score 3):

Можно либо передавать значение в конструктор

```
class Le
{
    public static $db;

    public function __construct($db) {
        // Ваш код
        self::$db = $db;
    }
}

// Получили ресурс
$db = 'Ресурс';
$obj = new Le($db);

echo Le::$db;
```

Либо получать значение прямо в конструкторе

```
class Le
{
    public static $db;

    public function __construct() {
        // Получили ресурс
        $db = 'Ресурс';
        // Ваш код
        self::$db = $db;
    }
}

$obj = new Le;

echo Le::$db;
```

А далее обращаться уже к статическому свойству класса $db.

Comment: 'db' это по сути класс в функции. Т.Е через него я стартую pdo драйвер базы mysql.
Добавил self::$db = $db;
Теперь пишет: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Access to undeclared static property: le::$db in C:\servers\WWW\engine\engine.php:9 Stack trace: #0 C:\servers\WWW\index.php(3): le->__construct() #1 {main} thrown in C:\servers\WWW\engine\engine.php on line 9

Comment: @user272078 есть такое понятие "область видимости" - почитайте о ней, сперва на примерах пользовательских функций - там проще будет понять, как передавать параметры, т.к. пользовательская функция по сути, это тот же метод в теле класса, с не большими отличиями.